# Question about Bayesian inference of the distribution of a categorical variable

Tags: bayesian, inference, model, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to build a Bayesian models in JAGS that infers probabilities about count data for past events and having trouble setting up the model.

The observable data: pairs of count data and times. The counts range from 0 to 25 and the time variable ranges from 200 years before the present to 5000. So one example is a pair (0, 250), which is a count of zero that was attested 250 years ago.

The prior for the count data is a multinomial distribution that specifies a probability for each count, e.g., count 0 has a value of .31.

I want to take the observed data (the pairs of counts and times) and want to infer a probability distribution over the count data for a time that precedes all of my observed times. So let's say my earliest count dates to 3000 years before the present. I want a probability distribution for the count data at 3500 years ago.

What I'm having trouble with is the prior for the rate of change of the count data. The count data has the following properties:

1. Counts change very slowly (e.g., on average there is either a loss or an addition every few hundred years)
2. It is much more likely that the count will decrease than increase

Since the observable count data is a function of the prior multinomial distribution plus the amount of time each count has had to change and its rate of change. I am struggling to understand what sort of graphical model I would need to do this. Do I need to set up a Poisson distribution as a hyper parameter that will determine rate of change?

I would be grateful for any suggestions or pointers to literature that tries to model similar data.

Comment: Unless you have some good reason to believe otherwise (such that count observations are correlated across time), this seems like a simple regression problem: $Y\sim \mathrm{Pois}(f(X))$.

Comment: Yes, the count observations are correlated across time.

Comment: My question is whether there is some underlying assumption/understanding of the process generating the data such that counts from two different years should be correlated, rather than following a pattern based on year? If the former is true, then you have a sequence/time series and should use a model that generates sequences/time series. Otherwise, regression should suffice.